# Kotlin overload resolution ambiguity in Pair with reference to println

Tags: kotlin, println, ambiguity

Using a reference to println as a Pair element fails when the reference is the first in the Pair.

```
    >>> 0 to ::println
```

produces

```
    (0, fun println(): kotlin.Unit)
```

but

```
    >>> ::println to 0
```

gives

```
    error: overload resolution ambiguity
```

Explicitly defining the pair using Pair() works fine in both cases.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: That's weird, I would expect all of those to be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here that you might find interesting.

Given that there's one version of `println` that takes no parameters, when you don't specify the type you expect `::println` to be of, that's the version that's selected. [citation needed: I couldn't find any documentation/specification that says that this is the case, but that's what trying this out in Kotlin 1.2.71 shows]

The second piece is that the `infix fun` "`to`" is an extension method, so the type needs to be resolved before being able to invoke it.

For this reason, `0 to ::println` gets automatically considered a `Pair<Int, () -> Unit>`.

To test this out, you can try the following:

```
fun foo(a: Int): Unit = Unit
fun foo(): Unit = Unit

val a = 0 to ::foo  // the non-parameter version is selected
val b = ::foo to 0  // there's ambiguity. What extension method "to" to call?
val c:  Pair<(Int) -> Unit, Int> = ::foo to 0 // No ambiguity, as I'm specifying the type
```

Now, if there are no overloads:

```
fun foo(a: Int): Unit = Unit

val a = 0 to ::foo  // No ambiguity, there's only one to choose from
val b = ::foo to 0  // Same here, there's only one option
```

Finally, it gets interesting when you only have options WITH parameters:

```
fun foo(a: Int): Unit = Unit
fun foo(a: Int, b: Int): Unit = Unit

val a = 0 to ::foo  // There's no non-parameter version to call, so there's ambiguity
val b = ::foo to 0  // there's ambiguity. What extension method "to" to call?
```